# Deny access to favicon

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have 2 domains using the same httpdocs folder, what i need to do is to deny the access to the favicon when the request comes from one of my domains or simply redirect it to another favicon file.
I've been trying to solve this by editing the .htaccess file but i can't figure out how to make the RewriteRule to work.

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe show what you have, so people can correct it

Answer (score 0):

To deny access to the `favicon.ico` completely you can use a `<Files>` directive in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files favicon.ico>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

If you wanted to redirect instead, you might do it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host1.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico /host1-favicon.ico

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host2.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico /host2-favicon.ico
```

Comment: I'm trying with this lines and it's not working


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico /second-favicon.ico


Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated my example.  You shouldn't put the leading `/` on the `favicon.ico` pattern.

Comment: When using the deny access <Location> directive I get an Internal Server Error 500 and the page doesn't load.

Comment: @Polypheme - yup, you are correct. I've updated. Thanks for catching that.